# TypeLoadException on mouse_event

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Everytime I run my application, I get this

[image]

I think it's occurring in the following code:

```
DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
```

Edit: I fixed it by adding another DllImport ontop of the mouse_event varaible and switching all the constants to:

```
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
```

Answer (score 1):

See this documentation: [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/mouse_event.html)

Try copy-pasting this code (or remove the dllImport parameters):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
```

Comment: I still have the same error, instead in my Error List it says: Warning 1 Method, operator, or accessor 'GameApplication.Methods.mouse_event(uint, uint, uint, uint, System.UIntPtr)' is marked external and has no attributes on it. Consider adding a DllImport attribute to specify the external implementation.

Comment: Did you tried to use the `UIntPtr` instead of `int` (in the `dwExtraInfo`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the difference dll put `[DllImport(@"user32.dll")]` above every your function use this dll. If you use C# dll, why don't you just add reference for it?